# Ideas for protecting an sEMG system from external problems

Tags: safety, protection, over-voltage-protection

I am designing a pcb to work as a human-machine interface. Here is the simplified schematic:
[image]

The idea is to connect a custom sEMG acquisition system to esp32 and also a pcb to control vibrotactile actuators to the same esp32. These vibrotactile actuators work with 4V max. I was wondering if there is something I need to do to protect the user in any case of system failure, since I am working with actuators (even if they are low-power).